# how to compare 2 version of dll's and find the modified methods

Tags: mono.cecil, disassembly

Note: I don't have pdb files for those dll's.

I tried to compare the dll's using " Mono.Cecil" but was able to succeed in comparing the method signature only.

Is there a way to compare the method body and find the modified methods.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be maybe helpful if you compare the different instructions of the methods?

E.g.:

```
List<Mono.Cecil.Cil.Instruction> listOfInstructionsOfMethod = method.Body.Instructions.ToList();
```

type of variable "method" is MethodDefinition